# In and out of PHP mode

Tags: php

I was starting to make sense of PHP just fine until I saw this little number. I'm confused as to what this logic is doing.

> ```
> <?php
> if (strpos($_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'], 'MSIE') !== FALSE) {
> ?>
> <h3>strpos() must have returned non-false</h3>
> <p>You are using Internet Explorer</p>
> <?php
> } else {
> ?>
> <h3>strpos() must have returned false</h3>
> <p>You are not using Internet Explorer</p>
> <?php
> }
> ?>
> ```

When does one need to jump in and out of PHP mode even in the middle of a PHP block.

How does this method help or say differ from just using PHP to dynamically output HTML? 
this style doesn't seem consistent to me with PHP is this recommended?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The more readable version of this (notwithstanding separate templating systems) would be:

```
<?php if (strpos($_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'], 'MSIE') !== false) : ?>
    <h3>strpos() must have returned non-false</h3>
    <p>You are using Internet Explorer</p>
<?php else : ?>
    <h3>strpos() must have returned false</h3>
    <p>You are not using Internet Explorer</p>
<?php endif; ?>
```

But yes, this is commonly used. It's good because:

- it's fast, the parser just skips right over the non-PHP blocks without evaluating them
- it's simple
- no messed up quotes or unreadable backslash orgies
- good syntax highlighting even in not-so-advanced editors

Comment: I don't understand how you can have an If, Else statements alone in a php command. You did <?php else : ?> that looks strange.

Comment: Also, remember PHP started as an HTML pre-processor.  The 'skipping in and out of php mode' thing is something you'll encounter when PHP is essentially being used as a template engine.  Not the prettiest to read, but can be easier than a bunch of echo calls.

Comment: @Shire The PHP parsing logic when encountering a `?>` is simply to output everything until the next `<?php` as is; it's that simple. Nothing else about "the logic" changes.

Comment: I'm new to PHP coming from a Java background so this is relatively mind-boggling to me. It's fun I admit but just odd. Thanks though.

Comment: -1 for this "fast" and "skipping"

Comment: @Shire Understand that PHP started the other way around: you had little snippets of PHP code inside an HTML document to make *some* parts of it "dynamic". It has just become a "proper programming language" (debatable, I know ;)) over the years.

Comment: @Your Seriously? *That's* what you're going to complain about? Are you saying parsing a string literal and `echo`ing it is faster and more preferable?

Comment: it's like "single vs. double", you know. Neither of them "faster".

Comment: @Your Would it appease you more if I mentioned this further down the list instead...?

Comment: Look at you two epic users bickering over 2 points. Tsk tsk ;)

Comment: @Alien I couldn't care less about 2 points, it's more about HisCommonSense being seemingly out of it sometimes. :)

Comment: Yeah, -1 Your Common Sense's comment.  Having the server send text is faster than having PHP parse a possibly huge double-quoted string with variables and logic in it.  It's usually not a huge difference, but it can be a difference.

Comment: In terms of speed you're more likely to notice a lag issue with the site in relation to DNS look-up, system overhead in relation to executing browser functions, and delay in transfer over the pipe than you would **EVER** notice based on programming style unless it's some ridiculously unnecessary loop.

Comment: @Absolute Sure, I'd never debate that. Just pointing out that this is the fastest style of outputting anything, regardless of how important that point really is.

Answer (score 7):

It's not really different as far as the browser is concerned. It's more semantics, keeping the display code out of the logic code. Generally for something like the above, you'd have a view (M **V** C) and would abstract as much of the PHP from the HTML as possible, so, if you had web *designers* on the team who didn't know PHP it would be easier for them to modify the HTML.

Comment: +1 for mentioning the design team. Collaborative-friendly code is the best in my opinion :)

Comment: This answer kind of goes off into a completely different direction. You often need *some* logic within templates one way or the other. This question is just about the style of jumping in and out of PHP blocks, not what these blocks do.

Comment: Different direction than what? We both agree it's a stylistic decision and not a behavioral one. I tried to answer why I think people choose this style, and in my experience it's because they are generally worried about front-end devs screwing things up. You mentioned in your comment about escaping quotes and whatnot. It's one less risk.

Answer (score 2):

It's just a different style. There is really no performance difference (execution-wise) as long as you're accustomed to working that way the will be no performance difference production-wise either.

Some people code that way because in the editors when you encapsulate HTML inside of PHP the editor doesn't colorize the HTML formatting like it does when you're dealing with HTML alone.

[image: PHP-Only Formatting]

That being said...

### When you have to make major design changes with this style of formatting you have to rewrite ALL OF THE CODE.

[image: html-mixed]

**Issues with this style:**

It has its drawbacks, for instance when you start including a lot of files of various types because you're using things like Javascript it makes it harder to track down a problem and it is much more of a rookie programming style.

1. It leads to cutting corners in other aspects of programming
2. When you're using classes in PHP they tend to look like classes in Javascript
3. It's harder to use this method and follow the new rules of few includes on the internet in terms of Javascript and CSS.
4. If there are in-line references to other files or line numbers, now they're modified by formating
5. If you have a team of developers and a team of graphic designers or web designers they will both need to be in the same code (which leads to chaos).
6. Most designers know CSS and Javascript, jquery, and maybe a little Ajax. Most developers know HTML and the language they're programming in. So it can cause problems when the two are intermingled.

In the following screenshot we're using `PHP`, `Javascript`, and `HTML` all in-line with one another. If there is an error in the `DOM` for `Javascript` you would need to hunt for the lines of code in this `include()` in `PHP` (assuming you're using PHP includes for the headers after the code was written on the front-end and served. It would not cause a PHP error, so due to the lack of documenting the code, it could be in *x* number of includes to hunt through. When you do a search on all code for `for` or `if` it would match several same files.

If there were errors with the formatting in `Javascript` or `HTML` that broke the `PHP` you would have to hunt for those in the `include`. It's very messy, but it's all technically functional. If people only program the way they know it can become very confusing. And astronomically hard to debug.

[image: This is hard to debug.]

If you're up against an issue or issues like these, then present them to the team's manager (if you're not the manager) and explain about loss of time and added programming hours for budgets. They'll get the idea fast when it all translates to money.

Note: *All screenshots are from Dreamweaver with default code coloring*

Comment: There's something I don't quite understand about your first example, the one where you're using `if (!preg_match('!MSIE!',$_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'])) {`. If I run that code when using Firefox for example, should that return `You are not using Internet Explorer`?

Comment: You're welcome. So, I take it that should've been a `if(preg_match...`?

Comment: @Fred it's updated. I wasn't really reading the code, only taking screenshots. I've edited that image so now it also says nothing about `strpos()`.

Comment: It's my **editor blood** that got the best of me. LOL! An old job I had many many moons ago. Cheers A.Ƶ.

Comment: @Fred It's funny how the world changes and we all change with it.

Comment: True, and change is good for sure, yet I'm still using **"Old School"** methods, and in more ways than one, or is that `none`? *Yeah, I'm an 'ol Dawg* ;-) Have a look at my bio/profile, it'll explain most of it. lol

Comment: @Fred I started Assembly in the 80s and worked in Paradox in the early 90s. Too funny.

Comment: I dabbled in assembler as well, but like my bio/profile says, my (computer) life took a **right turn** when I discovered Windows 3.1 Paintbrush (it was amazing at the time lol). Worked with XT's and an Apple IIe <= with a **digitizer** (it was state-of-the-art at the time hahaha!!, mid 80s) Now, it's as if **1.3 ms**, is too much time to wait. Ah, but I'm patient, I grow **cactus**; really. **Paradox**?! Wow, that takes me wayyyy back!

Answer (score 1):

> I'm confused as to what this logic is doing.

It is going In and out of PHP mode. An important note - it's PHP interpreter is going here, not browser.

> this style doesn't seem consistent to me

You need to think it over. Add some windy javascript and styles to this silly HTML and consider the resulting code again.

> with PHP is this recommended?

Definitely.
That's actually the only sane way to output blocks of XHTML keeping it's look, structure, highlighting and indentation.

Comment: Who's still using XHTML?

Answer (score 0):

This is simply another style of PHP – if you are working with a large block of HTML and want to print out a variable or two, loop over an array or use some simple IF statement then this approach is perhaps ideal for your purpose.